# Syncronize Hyper-V - Dual Boot Windows 10/Server 2012R2

Tags: multi-boot, hyper-v, powershell-4.0

On my PC I dual boot between Windows 10 and Server 2012R2. I keep the drive mappings exactly the same only flopping the C: and the Z: drive. I have Hyper-V role installed on both installations. I have kept the Switch Names the same in each hyper-v environment.

When I boot into Server 2012R2 I only have the machines that I created while in Server2012R2 and vice versa with windows 10
If all the virtual hard disks were in the same folder i.e. e:\hyper-v\virtual hard disks it would be simple to just do a DIR of the hard disk folder and create equivalent virtual machines. But I don't have it this way since some virtual machines are very disk intensive so I put them on a separate spindle as disk iops aren't that great for SATA drives even SATA3 (6GB) ports.  i.e. each DC which replicates folders since I use folder redirection and roaming profiles for these VM's

What I'd like is some way that I can synchronize  the two Hyper-V environments.. with 2 machines would be child's play but this is on the same machine. That and the virtual disks are spread out among 12 disks

Both environments have the same switch names and disk drive letters

Since I spend most of my time in Windows 10 that vm environment has 33 virtual machines but S2K12R2 only has 3

I've tried powershell import-vm -path  -register with no joy

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm out of luck. Server 2012R2 uses configuration version 5.0 and all of mine are 7.0.  Guess I have to export and import or do it all manually.